# Why does Knex (PostgreSQL) query always return empty object while query by email retrieved from JSON POST request?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to build my first react app. In the front end, to sign/log in, when a registered user submits his/her email and correct password, in my server side code for response, a query is done by the retrieved email in PostgreSQL database.

Signin component code:

```
const handleSignin = (req, res, db, bcrypt) => {
const { email, password } = req.body;
if (!email || !password) {
  return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
}

/*** There are 2 tables: users & login **/
/*** START (code for debugging) ***/
console.log("email retrieved from req: ", email);
console.log("length of email retrieved from req: ", email.length);
const check = "tithi@gmail.com";
console.log("length of hard-coded email, check: ", check.length);
db.select('name', 'email').from('users')
      .where('email', '=', email)
      .then(user => {
          console.log("query by email retrieved from req: ", user[0]);
      })
db.select('name', 'email').from('users')
      .where('email', '=', check)
      .then(user => {
          console.log("query by email(check): ", user[0]);
      })
/*** END (code for debugging) ***/

/*** You can ignore this part ***/
db.select('email', 'hash').from('login')
  .where('email', '=',  email)
  .then(data => {
    const isValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, data[0].hash);
    if (isValid) {
      return db.select('*').from('users')
        .where('email', '=', email)
        .then(user => {
          res.json(user[0])
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get user'))
    } else {
      res.status(400).json('wrong password')
    }
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('wrong email'))
}

module.exports = {
  handleSignin: handleSignin
}
```

I used Knex here. **The query always returns an empty object. I've checked, the user with this email exists in database.** But query by other attributes or even, an email assigned inside the code works.

output:

```
email retrieved from req:  tithi@gamil.com
length of email retrieved from req:  15
length of hard-coded email, check:  15
query by email retrieved from req:  undefined
query by email(check):  { name: 'tithi', email: 'tithi@gmail.com' }
```

The email is retrieved correctly that is shown in the console output image.
Another problem is, **query by email works right when I input these via front end, running on my localhost. But query always returns empty object while I POST via Postman application or the back end deployed on Heroku.**

Comment: Look for spaces or other invisible characters at the end of the email address.

Comment: Hi! Please post code in the body of your question (rather than link to images) it really helps people answer your question more quickly. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't see results when sending the request via Postman is that you're sending the string `tithi@gamil.com`, which is not contained in your database. Fix the typo and you should see results.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26596557)

Comment: It does, in fact. The results he's seeing are entirely explained by the difference in inputs. However, I can add a sentence if you feel it's insufficient.

Comment: My database contains the string I sent via Postman, 'tithi@gmail.com'. To check this, the other query is done by the same string (not sent in request but hard-coded) and the query doesn't return empty object.
The length of these two strings are same, so why are the query results different? What have you meant by the difference in inputs?

Comment: Look closely at your debugging output.  `gmail` and `gamil` are not the same string.